# How to write a inline for loop in scala3?

Tags: scala, inline, scala-3

I have write some performance critical codes in scala, and encountered codes as following time by time:

```
var index = start - 1
while {index += 1; index < end} do something
```

Then I want to write a inline version to avoid the `var index` and `while { .. }` again:

```
inline def forward(start: Int, end: Int)(inline body: Int => Unit): Unit =
    if start < end then
        body(start)
        forward(start + 1, end)(body)
```

I supposed that `forward(start, end){ something }` will generated almost the same code as the hand write `while {}`.

But I encountered a wired [compile message](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dpFne25fQXGHEr6fsFoRYw) confused me very much:

```
object InlineFor:
    val n: Int = 1

    inline def forward(start: Int, end: Int)(inline body: Int => Unit): Unit =
        if start < end then
            body(start)
            forward(start + 1, end)(body)

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
        forward(0, 1)(println)  // This is OK
        forward(0, n)(println)  // This is failed
```

> Maximal number of successive inlines (32) exceeded, Maybe this is
> caused by a recursive inline method? You can use -Xmax-inlines to
> change the limit.

Is there any thing wrong of the code? 3x very much.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all: you have a inline **recursive** method.

This is only supported with a known number of iterations (at compile time) and with a maximum number defined by a compiler flag `-Xmax-inlines`.

There's no way the compiler can inline the code without knowing `n` in your code.

Note that you don't need `inline` at all in your code, just annotate your method with `@tailrec` to **enforce it is tail recursive and the compiler will generate optimized code**.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this if you change the type of n to `1`:

```
object InlineFor:
    val n: 1 = 1

    inline def forward(start: Int, end: Int)(inline body: Int => Unit): Unit =
        if start < end then
            body(start)
            forward(start + 1, end)(body)

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
        forward(0, n)(println)  // ok again
```

Reason is that the compiler needs to know the values of `start` and `end` *on the type-level* to properly determine `if start < end`.

However: **I do not think inline recursion is what you are looking for**. You would run into the same compiler error again if you call `forward(0, 32)(println)` because then you'd really reach the default limit of recursive inlines (which is 32).

You should be aware that (drastically simplified) each call to an inlined function will result in the call being replaced by the function-body. So instead of a loop, the resulting bytecode will contain n instances of the bytecode of `body`. (And that's the reason why there is a limit for recursive inline calls.)

If you're using Intellij IDEA: there is a "Show bytecode" option under the "view" menu. I suggest you use that and observe how your bytecode grows if you increase the value of `n`.

Comment: But why the compiler needs to know the values of start on type-level even if I declare the `start : Int` rather than `inline start: Int`? And I neither declare the `if start < end then` as `inline if start < end then`.

Comment: Because only if the compiler knows the value of `start` (and `end`!) it will know when it reached the point where it does not need to replace the line `forward(start + 1, end)(body)` by another instance of the `if start < end //.. block`.